# This code in VB net

Tags: c#, vb.net, encryption, reflector, decompiler

I have decompiled an vb.net application with reflector

All string are encrypted with this method:

```
Public Shared Function smethod_0(ByVal string_0 As String) As String
    Dim length As Integer = string_0.Length
    Dim chArray As Char() = New Char(length  - 1) {}
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To chArray.Length - 1
        Dim ch As Char = string_0.Chars(i)
        Dim num3 As Byte = CByte((ch Xor (length - i)))
        Dim num4 As Byte = CByte(((ch >> 8) Xor i))
        chArray(i) = DirectCast(((num4 << 8) Or num3), Char)
    Next i
    Return String.Intern(New String(chArray))
End Function
```

This method receives an input string like this:

```
"j" & ChrW(354) & ChrW(623) & ChrW(868)
```

and returns a readable string.

How can I convert this code in vb.net or c#?

The Vb.net compiler complains that this code is not correcte because xor is not defined for a char/int combination.

Comment: Try switching Reflector over to C# output - it tends to produce more accurate C# code than it does VB.NET

Comment: aside from the fact that this is unlikely to be a strong encryption (if any at all) I tend to find it rude to **borrow** someones code - if you know that this is VB ask the author to give you the original code - if he refuses go on and write it yourself!

Answer (score 0):

C# version (only for educational reasons - keeping similar code as possible):

```
public static string encrypt(string s)
{
    int length = s.Length, i = 0;
    char[] chArray = new char[length];
    byte b1, b2;
    char ch;
    for (i = 0; i <= chArray.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        ch = s[i];
        b1 = Convert.ToByte((ch ^ (length - i)));
        b2 = Convert.ToByte(((ch >> 8) ^ i));
        chArray[i] = (char)((b2 << 8) | b1);
    }
    return string.Intern(new string(chArray));
}
```

Comment: line b1 = Convert.t((ch ^ (length - i))); return this error: Value too large or too small for an unsigned byte

Comment: It's obvious that this happens when the string you want to encode exceeds 255 characters. The code you found is for short length strings. Larger strings should initially split to shorted ones.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved in this way:

```
    public static string encrypt(string string_0)
    {
        int length = string_0.Length;
        char[] chArray = new char[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < chArray.Length; i++)
        {
            char ch = string_0[i];
            byte num3 = (byte)(ch ^ (length - i));
            byte num4 = (byte)((ch >> 8) ^ i);
            chArray[i] = (char)((num4 << 8) | num3);
        }

        File.AppendAllText("decript.txt", Environment.NewLine + string_0 + "  =  " + string.Intern(new string(chArray)));
```

return string.Intern(new string(chArray));

```
    }
```

Thanks for help